# Counting by Item & Channel by First Two Months Sold

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Following up on my last question, [Counting Items based on First Month Sold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067500/counting-items-based-on-first-month-sold), I need to count items by the first two months they were sold but also need to group by channel along with item, along with total item qty sold as well.

See sample code below

```
DECLARE @sales table(
itemnumber int,
saledate date,
channeltype varchar,
ordid varchar, 
orditemqty int)

INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-03', Channel2, 1, 5)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-03', Channel2, 2, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-03', Channel2, 3, 2)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-03', Channel2, 4, 3)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-03', Channel2, 4, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-04', Channel2, 5, 5)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-26-04', Channel2, 5, 7)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-04', Channel1, 5, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-04', Channel2, 6, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-04', Channel1, 7, 2)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-04', Channel2, 8, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-04', Channel2, 8, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-04', Channel2, 8, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 9, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 9, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 9, 10)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 9, 11)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 9, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 9, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 19, 7)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 19, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 25, 10)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 25, 11)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 25, 10)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 27, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 27, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 27, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 28, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 29, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-05', Channel1, 39, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-05', Channel2, 30, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-06', Channel1, 31, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-06', Channel1, 31, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-26-07', Channel1, 45, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-07', Channel2, 61, 3)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-07', Channel2, 61, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-07', Channel2, 61, 5)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-07', Channel2, 61, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-08', Channel1, 71, 2)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-08', Channel1, 71, 3)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-26-09', Channel1, 76, 5)
```

The output would look like the following

```
ITEMNO| CHANNELTYPE | YEARMONTH | COUNT | QTY
---------------------------------------------
43029 | Channel1    | 03-2011   | 0     | 0
43029 | Channel2    | 03-2011   | 7     | 29
43030 | Channel1    | 04-2011   | 11    | 84
43030 | Channel2    | 04-2011   | 9     | 39
43050 | Channel1    | 05-2011   | 4     | 19
43050 | Channel2    | 05-2011   | 2     | 13 
43090 | Channel1    | 07-2011   | 2     | 5
43090 | Channel2    | 07-2011   | 4     | 20
```

A count would only appear if it was sold during the first two months within the first time the item was ordered, where it could be one of several channels (I'm using Channel1, and 2 as examples but there could be several) but will always have one channel.I'd want to display all channels and show a count of 0 if there isn't anything there with the quantity also being 0 in that case (example, an item sold in one channel during those first two months but not the second channel).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does need a cross join now!

```
DECLARE @sales table(
itemnumber int,
saledate date,
channeltype varchar(10),
ordid varchar, 
orditemqty int)

INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-03-26', 'Channel2', 1, 5)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-03-26', 'Channel2', 2, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-03-26', 'Channel2', 3, 2)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-03-26', 'Channel2', 4, 3)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-03-26', 'Channel2', 5, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-04-26', 'Channel2', 6, 5)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43029, '2011-04-26', 'Channel2', 7, 7)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-04-26', 'Channel1', 8, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-04-26', 'Channel2', 9, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-04-26', 'Channel1', 10, 2)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-04-26', 'Channel2', 11, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-04-26', 'Channel2', 12, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-04-26', 'Channel2', 13, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 14, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 15, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 16, 10)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 17, 11)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 18, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 19, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 20, 7)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 21, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 22, 10)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 23, 11)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 24, 10)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 25, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 26, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43030, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 27, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 28, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 29, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-05-26', 'Channel1', 30, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-05-26', 'Channel2', 31, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-06-26', 'Channel1', 32, 9)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-06-26', 'Channel1', 33, 1)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43050, '2011-07-26', 'Channel1', 34, 6)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-07-26', 'Channel2', 35, 3)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-07-26', 'Channel2', 36, 4)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-07-26', 'Channel2', 37, 5)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-07-26', 'Channel2', 38, 8)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-08-26', 'Channel1', 39, 2)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-08-26', 'Channel1', 40, 3)
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(43090, '2011-09-26', 'Channel1', 41, 5)

SELECT t.itemnumber, t.channeltype, 
right(convert(varchar, firstsaledate, 106), 8) AS firstsale, 
SUM(t.cnt) AS salecount, sum(t.qty) AS saleqty  
FROM 
    (
    SELECT fsdc.itemnumber, fsdc.firstsaledate, fsdc.channeltype, 
    CASE WHEN s.ordid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS cnt, 
    COALESCE(s.orditemqty, 0) qty  
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT fsd.itemnumber, fsd.firstsaledate, fsd.targetdate, 
        c.channeltype 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT mns.itemnumber, mns.firstsaledate, DATEADD(m, 2, 
            DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(mns.firstsaledate), MONTH(mns.firstsaledate), 1)) 
            as targetdate 
            FROM
                (
                SELECT itemnumber, Min(saledate) as firstsaledate  FROM @sales 
                GROUP BY itemnumber 
                ) mns
            ) fsd
            CROSS JOIN
                (
                SELECT DISTINCT channeltype FROM @sales
                ) c
        ) fsdc
    LEFT JOIN @sales s
        ON s.itemnumber = fsdc.itemnumber and s.channeltype = fsdc.channeltype 
        AND s.saledate < fsdc.targetdate
    ) t
GROUP BY t.itemnumber, t.channeltype, t.firstsaledate
```

Results

```
itemnumber  channeltype firstsale   salecount   saleqty
43029       Channel1    Mar 2011    0           0
43029       Channel2    Mar 2011    7           29
43030       Channel1    Apr 2011    11          84
43030       Channel2    Apr 2011    9           39
43050       Channel1    May 2011    4           19
43050       Channel2    May 2011    2           13
43090       Channel1    Jul 2011    2           5
43090       Channel2    Jul 2011    4           20
```

It is now a simple thing to change the number of months covered in the first period.  Just change the number of months in the dateadd function.

Comment: Question - how would I go about now getting results from the first two months from the first date purchase vs just the first month?

Comment: Do you want first two months summed together, or first month sales and second month sales?

Comment: First two months summed together

Comment: Unless first two months separately probably makes the most sense then I can always aggregate up

Comment: My pleasure.  Glad to have helped.

Comment: Quick question - on the new query, it looks like all zero value channels are not included and couldn't quite figure out how to splice in the zero values. Would you be able to amend that output back in? Appreciated!

Comment: Could you give me some sample data that does not work?  I was getting correct results with the sample I had, so I assumed all was ok.

Comment: Sorry just tested something - I tried adding a new channel with no sales in first two months!  Not included in result!  I'll look into it later, if that's ok.  Just popping out now for a drink with my wife - its 10.12 pm here.

Comment: That's fine, I also neglected the fact that the data has quantity of items and not just item numbers so along with counting the number of items, I also need to sum up the quantity of items sold. Currently the query counts the number of item numbers, as total items, so I revised the sample data above to include quantity as well as I was getting the wrong result in further testing. Oversight on my part! Hope it's not too troubling to revise. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121651/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-danimov82).

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit tricky.  One method is to generate all the rows you want with a `cross join` and then use a `left join` to bring in the count:

```
with icym as (
      select s.item_id, s.channel,
             format(saledate, 'yyyy-mm') as yyyymm,
             count(*) as cnt
      from @sales s
      group by s.item_id, s.channel,
               format(saledate, 'yyyy-mm') as yyyymm,
     )
select iy.item_id, iy.yyyymm, c.channel, coalesce(icym.cnt, 0)
from (select distinct s.item_id, yyyymm from icym) iy cross join
     (select distinct channel from icym) c left join
     icym
     on icym.item_id = iy.item_id and icym.yyyymm = iy.yyyymm and
        icym.channel = c.channel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need all distinct channels and then do a left join like below..

```
;With cte
as
(select 
itemnumber,saledate,channeltype,
dense_rank() over (partition by  itemnumber order by cast(month(convert(datetime,saledate,103)) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(year(convert(datetime,saledate,103)) as varchar(4))) as rownum
from
#temp
),
channel
as
(
select distinct channeltype from #temp)
select 
c.channeltype,
 itemnumber,
cast(month(convert(datetime,saledate,103)) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(year(convert(datetime,saledate,103)) as varchar(4)) as datetimesale,
isnull(sum(rownum),0) as salescount
from channel c
left join
cte c1
on c.channeltype=c1.channeltype
where rownum=1
group by
itemnumber,
cast(month(convert(datetime,saledate,103)) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(year(convert(datetime,saledate,103)) as varchar(4)),
c.channeltype
```

Comment: I must be re-naming things incorrectly. If the table is called Orders and the columns are called ItemNo, ChanType, and OrderDate, what would need to be swapped in your query? 

I am getting a number of invalid column name errors when attempting to run it thinking I'd replaced everything correctly.

Comment: saledate for orderdate,chantype-channeltype,itemno remains same

Comment: The query ran but it showed that first orders for a given item was in Jan 2015 for the correct counts per channel, however when I checked the data the first time that item sold was in 2013 then again in 2014. What could I provide that would be helpful to diagnose?